# Your request cannot be processed at this time. The site administrator has been alerted

Tags: community

I get this error every time I try to create a new user for community. Why?

> Your request cannot be processed at this time. The site administrator has been alerted

I have selected allow external user and self-registration.

Answer (score 7):

Your registration page may be using an email address as the Username of the Salesforce user record.  User names need to be unique, so registration will fail if the email address has already been used as the Username for another salesforce user id.

Comment: This suggestion worked like a charm ... just changed the email id to something which is not used by any User in the Org during self registration ...

Comment: How could I change the error text?

Answer (score 5):

Here are [some of the reasons this error can occur](http://carvingintheclouds.blogspot.com/2014/09/your-request-cannot-be-processed-at.html):

> - **The community is not published.** In case you're
>   working with a community that is offline or in Preview status, you
>   need to publish the community before self-registration will work.
> - **The Account Owner does not have a User Role assigned.** If
>   you're creating a new Account record on the fly, especially in B2C
>   situations, you need to make sure you assign a default account owner
>   that *also* has a User Role value. Any role will do, and you can
>   use either a workflow rule or Apex to perform the assignment.
> - **The site guest user does not have Create and Read permissions
>   on the Account and Contact objects.** Edit Public Access Settings
>   for the community's Force.com site to grant these permissions, along
>   with field permissions for any fields that are included on the
>   self-registration form. Note that by default the site's profile will
>   *not* have these permissions.
> - **Self-registration is
>   not enabled for the community.** Go to Manage Communities, click
>   Edit and make sure the Login settings show that self-registration is
>   enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Check your email (or ask the sys admin to do so if you are not the admin). It will have the actual error message in it.

Very often beside of the mentioned reasons, the reason for this error is the ProfileId missing